# what is the difference between of and from

Tags: grammar

Can any one help me to configure what is the difference between "with 10 days of" and "within 10 days from"

Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: You don't provide enough context.  Also, do you realize one of your examples says "with" and the other says "within"?

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience caused,

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that isn't what configure means. You don't configure the difference.  You learn the difference.  Configuring is what you did when you wrote those two phrases.

The difference is:

"With 10 days of" is a preposition that introduces a period of time of 10 days that are not yet attached (and may never be) to any particular point in time and may not even be contiguous.

As in: **"With 10 days of sick leave left she decided to sleep in".**

"Within 10 days from" is a limit of 10 days after whatever point in time that is about to be mentioned.  This might turn out to be less than 10 days after whenever time you are about to mention.

As in: **"Within 10 days from the issuance of this ticket you must arrange payment with the court or schedule an appearance."**

If you want the question in the title answered instead I suggest you reword your question body.

Comment: I think maybe the @OP meant 'figure' instead of 'configure'; figure, in this instance, would mean understand.

Comment: yes, but if I'm going to guess I'd rather state my assumptions.

Comment: Completely understandable. :)